# Project Euler 1 does not print out all digits?

Tags: java

> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

My program works for siphoning out all the multiples of 3 and 5, but when I run it to 1000 it only prints out the multiples of 3 and 5 from 363 onwards.

My question is, why? This is my code:

```
class threeAndFive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
            } else if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample of output:

The first 7 lines of output are

```
363
365
366
369
370
372
375
```

The last 7 lines of output are

```
985
987
990
993
995
996
999
```

So how come, if judging by my for loop it should iterate from 3 right up to 999, it is starting output at 363?

EDIT

I found that I was meant to be finding the SUM, not printing out the numbers. 
Either way, my question still stands.

Comment: You don't need the last else if, it will be caught by either of the two previous conditions.

Comment: Though it won't change your result, I would actually suggest changing it to `if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)`

You shouldn't need any other if/else statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is working perfectly. Your IDE (presumably Eclipse) is simply running out of display room, and won't show you the previous lines. It is possible to configure the number of lines that will be stored in the output console. You could also print the numbers out with just spaces between them and get around the limitation that way.

Comment: Ahh .. the old 'fizzbuzz' test ... :-)

Comment: Thanks. However, I was only running it through a command prompt window, but presumably your statement still stands because of the limited capability of cmd.

Comment: Most likely so. You can just cut the upper limit of the loop down to 200 and see if the first numbers are printing or not - they won't magically quit working if you bump it to 1000, leaving my answer as the only likely explanation. I believe you can also configure the history size for the command prompt, as well.

Answer (score 1):

The order of if statements is also wrong in terms of logic.

```
if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) 
{
       System.out.println(i);
}
else if (i % 3 == 0) 
{
       System.out.println(i);
} 
else if (i % 5 == 0) 
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: He shouldn't even need the && statement. `if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)` or `if (i % 3 == 0) { ... } else if (i % 5 == 0) { ... }`. The order of the statements doesn't matter.

Comment: Everyone appears to be thinking of the conventional fizzbuzz test. Similar to this, but just different enough to mess us all up.